# Can't render ruby code inside CoffeScript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a simple CoffeScript file in the `/assets/javascript` pipeline that is working fine when adding CoffeScript to it.

If I add a simple `<%= puts "hello world" %>` on top of it I expect it to render "Hello World" on the file, yet I get this error message

```
throw Error("ExecJS::ProgramError: Error: Parse error on line 1: Unexpected 'COMPARE'\n  (in /Users/user/Sites/app/app/assets/javascripts/application/application.js.coffee)")
```

Any idea what is preventing me to render Ruby and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a file extension `.erb` *before* the `.coffee` extension. `application.js.erb.coffee`

Answer (score 2):

did you try adding `.erb` to the file name to enable ruby preprocessing?